# Run Postcode Through Function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I've written this function that takes an unformatted postcode and formats it with the correct spacing and formatting:

```
function formatPostcode(dirtyPostcode) {
  var up = dirtyPostcode.toUpperCase();
  var remove_spacing = up.split(" ");
  var add_space = remove_spacing.join("");
  var postcode = [add_space.slice(0, -3), " ", add_space.slice(-3)].join('');

  return postcode;
}
```

I've also got a form that lets users enter a postcode and pushes it to a Firebase object that I've got set up. I'd like to run the submitted postcode through my `formatPostcode()` function before pushing it to Firebase.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<form role="form" ng-submit="createHospital(newHospital)">
  <input type="text" ng-model="newHospital.address.postcode">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And my JS like this:

```
var rootRef = new Firebase('URL');
var placesRef = rootRef.child('places');

function createHospital(hospital) {
  placesRef.push(newHospital);
}

$scope.createHospital = createHospital;
```

How can I intergrate my `formatPostcode()` function into my `createHospital()` function so the postcode is formatted before it's pushed.

I'm racking my brain here. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `function createHospital(hospital) {
  hospital.address.postcode = formatPostcode(hospital.address.postcode);
  placesRef.push(hospital);
}`

Comment: Does my `formatPostcode` need to be binded to my `$scope`??

Comment: No but it should be declared at the same level than `createHospital` or higher (available for use, for example in the same controller).

Comment: Hmm, the postcode is showing up in the object in its unformatted form. Any ideas?

Comment: @Absor It looks like I was running into a problem with `.split(' ')`... Is this not supported in Angular? Is it better to use `.replace(/\s+/g, '')`???

Comment: String.split is a regular JavaScript function, there is nothing Angular-specific about it. It also seems rather unlikely that Angular would hide such a basic function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split